# Retrofit 2 Raw JSON request using RequestBody

Tags: android, retrofit

I use Retrofit 2 library, and I need to send POST JSON request like this:

```
{
   "datetime": 0,
   "body": {
       "gymId": "17C1B14C-C21F-41EE-BF75-F0E7843DB638",
       "customerName": "test",
       "customerEmail": "test@test.ru",
       "content": "test"
   }
}
```

How i can send this request use RequestBody?

```
 Call<ApiClubRequest> clubContact(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
```

Or can easily make such a request?

This is my interface class with OkHttp settings.

```
public class RestClient {

private static ClassApiInterface WordClassApiInterface ;
private static String baseUrl = "http://my adddress" ;


public static WorldClassApiInterface getClient() {
    if (WordClassApiInterface == null) {
        OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                return response;
            }
        });

        Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        ApiInterface = client.create(ApiInterface.class);

    }
    return ClassApiInterface ;
}

public static  Call<ApiClubRequest> clubcontact(String gymId, String customerName, String
        customerEmail, String content){
    ClubContactRequest request = new ClubContactRequest();
    request.gymId = gymId;
    request.customerName = customerName;
    request.customerEmail = customerEmail;
    request.content = content;
    return ApiInterface.clubContact(request);
}

  @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/hotline")
    Call<ApiClubRequest> clubContact(@Body ClubContactRequest requestBody);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

Create a request class and create fields with the same name as in the JSON:

```
public class ClubContactRequest {

    public String gymId;
    public String customerName;   
    public String customerEmail;
    public String content;
}
```

Modify the POST @Body:

```
Call<ApiClubRequest> clubContact(@Body ClubContactRequest requestBody);
```

Then implement the request:

```
public Call<ApiClubRequest> clubcontact(String gymId, String customerName, String customerEmail, String content){
    ClubContactRequest request = new ClubContactRequest();
    request.gymId = gymId;
    request.customerName = customerName;
    request.customerEmail = customerEmail;
    request.content = content;
    return yourApiInterface.clubContact(request);
}
```

Comment: Ok. I did it. But it is not clear how send request in this structure RestClient.WorldClassApiInterface service = RestClient.getClient();
              Call<ApiClubRequest> call = service.clubContact(??????);

Comment: If you set up properly the restAdapter you can call like, clubContact("17C1B14C-C21F-41EE-BF75-F0E7843DB638", "test", "test@test.ru", "test");

Comment: Hmm, i have error. Error:(205, 52) error: method clubContact in interface WorldClassApiInterface cannot be applied to given types;
required: ClubContactRequest
found: String,String,String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length